# Why im getting ' Non-exhaustive patterns in function subcombina'?

Tags: list, haskell

im learning haskell and recursion with it, i have this function

```
type Coordenada = (Int,Int)
type Skyline = [Coordenada]

combina :: (Skyline, Skyline) -> Skyline
combina ([], x) = x
combina (x, []) = x
combina ((ii, ia):ri,(di, da):rd) = subcombina((ii, ia):ri,0) ((di, da):rd,0)
        where subcombina ((ii, ia):ri, ih) ((di, da):rd, dh)
                           | ii < di                = (ii, max ia dh)  : subcombina(ri,ih) ((di, da):rd, dh)
                           | otherwise              = (di, max ih da)  : subcombina((ii, ia):ri, ih) (rd, dh)
```

And im getting this error:

```
Exception: Skyline.hs:(26,11)-(28,92): Non-exhaustive patterns in function subcombina
```

Witch pattern im missing?

Explaining function:

combina (merge) receives a tuple of list of tuples, if one of them its empty, result the other.
Then, for left list of tuples, get first tuple by element and the tail, and same for right tuple, call subcombina (submerge) with this values and 0

subcombina receives same as combina with a integer value per tuple (tuple1,int1) (tuple2, int2), with those patterns:

If left value of head of left tuple is bigger than left value of head of right tuple return a tuple of (first value of head of left tuple, max of integers) concat with recursive call to subcombina with left list without head and same integer as parent and right list of parent right tuple side with same integer as parent.
If not something similar as above.

I hope its well explained.

Comment: btw. your explanation of the functions is just a rephrasing of your code, next time try to give an explanation in context (what are you trying to achieve), and sprinkle it with an example or two.

Comment: I strongly recommend turning on warnings with `-Wall`: this will help you detect these issues at compile time.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Im resolving skyline problem algorithm http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-7-the-skyline-problem/#disqus_thread this is merge function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are pattern matching on lists

```
subcombina ((_:_), (_:_)) = ..
```

matches on a non-empty tuple, what this error/warning tells you is that you have forgotten to take care of cases like

```
subcombina ([], something) = ..
subcombina (something, []) = ..
subcombina ([], []) = ..
```